# Como posso exibir um PDF pelo Delphi?

Tags: delphi, pdf

Preciso que o PDF seja exibido na tela da aplicação Delphi, sem que o usuário precise ter outro software instalado, como por exemplo, Adobe Reader ou Foxit. Utilizo o Delphi XE 10. Qual componente eu deveria usar?

Comment: Consegui através do componente WebBrowser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O AcroPDF (Acrobat Reader PDF ActiveX) permite isso, porém necessita do Acrobat Reader instalado.

Para o seu caso, o [Free JPDF Pascal](https://github.com/jepafi/Free-JPDF-Pascal) pode ajudar.
Dê uma olhada também na [Synopse PDF Engine](https://synopse.info/fossil/wiki?name=PDF%20Engine) e no [Gnostice PDFtoolkit](https://www.gnostice.com/PDFtoolkit_VCL.asp).